# Conditional formatting based on previous values in column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a list of numbers and I want to highlight duplicates.
It's already working in its current state with conditional formatting and a custom formula: `=COUNTIF(B:B;B1)>1`

However, I would like to improve on that.
I only want it to highlight the cells value, if the duplicate is within the last 150 rows of that column, or after the current cell.
I tried the first part with going backwards, like `=COUNTIF(B1000:B850;B1000)>1`, but the range always gets re-ordered again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try with*:

***Apply to range***: `B:B`

***Custom formula is***:

```
=countif(index(B:B;max(1;row()-149)):index(B:B;row()+149);B1)>1
```